# Flat array to multi dimensional array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array:

```
var sampleArray = [
  "CONTAINER",
  "BODY",
  "NEWS",
  "TITLE"];
```

I want to have the following output:

```
var desiredOutput = [{
        "CONTAINER": [{
            "BODY": [{
                "NEWS": [{
                    "TITLE": []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }];
```

How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Already tried with recursive loop, but it does not work, gives me undefined.

```
    dataChange(sampleArray);
    function dataChange(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            changeTheArray[data[i]] = data[i + 1];
            data.splice(i, 1);
            dataChange(changeTheArray[data[i]]);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```js
const sampleArray = ["CONTAINER", "BODY", "NEWS", "TITLE"];
const data = [];    // Starting element.
let current = data; // Pointer to the current element in the loop

sampleArray.forEach(key => {     // For every entry, named `key` in `sampleArray`,
    const next = [];             // New array
    current.push({[key]: next}); // Add `{key: []}` to the current array,
    current = next;              // Move the pointer to the array we just added.
});

console.log(data);
```

`{[key]: next}` is relatively new syntax. They're [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

This:

```
const a = 'foo';
const b = {[a]: 'bar'};
```

Is similar to:

```
const a = 'foo';
const b = {};
b[a] = 'bar';
```

---

You *could* re-write the `forEach` as a one-liner:

```js
const sampleArray = ["CONTAINER", "BODY", "NEWS", "TITLE"];
const data = [];    // Starting element.
let current = data; // Pointer to the current element in the loop

sampleArray.forEach(key => current.push({[key]: current = [] }));

console.log(data);
```

This `current.push` works a little counter-intuitively:

1. Construct a new element to push. This assigns a new value to `current`.
2. Push the new element to the *reference* `.push` was called on.

   - That reference is the value of `current` ***before*** `current = []`.

Comment: question askers are fickle beasts ;-)

Comment: I'd go for an additional temporary variable to avoid the dereference in your function's second line:   `let next = []; current.push({[key] : next}); current = next`

Comment: @Alnitak: Yea, I was a little surprised. Good suggestion :-)

Comment: Re: your edit - why abuse `.forEach` with poorly understood ordering of the use of that `current` variable when `.reduce` is specifically designed to handle that accumulation?    I had considered a similar solution but without reference to the language spec I couldn't be sure whether the assignment to `current = []` happens before or after the `.push`.

Comment: @Alnitak: The moment you call `.push`. the `this` variable in `.push` is set to the old value of `current`. That reference doesn't change. I'm not claiming it's a good piece of code. I just realized it was possible, and wanted to add it.

Comment: How can you be sure?  How do you know that the parameters aren't evaluated *before* the variable is used as the function's `this` object?  You may well be right, but code like that is very hard to reason about, and IMHO best avoided.  In other languages it definitely (well, probably...) _wouldn't_ work the way you describe.

Comment: It looks like you are right - see http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.3 but my comments above still stand.

Comment: Again, _"I'm not claiming it's a good piece of code."_ It's just interesting, and something the reader can maybe learn something from.

Answer (score 9):

This does what you're asking for, in one line, and with no additional variables:

```
let desiredOutput = sampleArray.reduceRight((obj, key) => [ { [key]: obj } ], []);
```

The `reduceRight` call, *starting from the right hand end of the array*, progressively accumulates the current data (seeded with the initial value of `[]`)  as the value of the single key in a new object `{ [key] : _value_ }` where that object is itself the single entry in an array `[ ... ]`.

Comment: Nice witchcraft... I tried to build a `reduce` method, but couldn't get it to work due to the accumulator moving down the tree... The `reverse` is a clever touch :D

Comment: @Xufox yeah, I was just reaching that conclusion myself while you were commenting - my original tests got confused by the fact that `.reverse()` does an _in place_ reversal and my test data had already been corrupted.  So using `.reduceRight` is actually better since it leaves the original array untouched.

Comment: @Cerbrus actually, `reduceRight()` is better.

Comment: @Cerbrus I also tried it with `reduce` and building on a value similar to `{data: [], referenceToInnerArray: []}`, but Alnitak got it done sooner…

Comment: Even better :D I had no idea there was such a thing as `reduceRight`...

Comment: @Cerbrus I had forgotten about it myself for a while - it's used far less frequently than `.reduce()`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i made a little [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0tv0qwg1/) :

```
var sampleArray = [
      "CONTAINER",
      "BODY",
      "NEWS",
      "TITLE"
    ], 
    generateArray = [], 
    tmp = null;

for(var i = 0; i < sampleArray.length; i++) {
  if(tmp===null){
    generateArray[sampleArray[i]] = {};
    tmp = generateArray[sampleArray[i]];
  }else{
    tmp[sampleArray[i]] = {};
    tmp = tmp[sampleArray[i]];
  }         
}

console.log(generateArray);
```